# How can i control session limit module?

Tags: 7, sessions

I am using [Session Limit](https://drupal.org/project/session_limit) module for restrict user to login into site from multiple browsers at a time.But here i am facing a problem is if user close the browser with out logout,then the session will not closed and the user is not able to login from same browser also.

To avoid this problem I set

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 0);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0);
```

But it does not work for me. If I close my browser even though the user session has not  closed.